# Use a custom function everywhere in the website

Tags: php, oop, laravel-5.1, slug

I come from the procedural PHP and am learning OOP with Laravel. What I learned so far is very interesting and will ease my developer's life (it's not my job btw).
So, for all my websites, I am using a slug property for all articles, categories, and so on.
I started to use the "str_slug" provided by Laravel which seems to do the job at 99%. The issue I get is when I have such title (in french): "J'ai mangé une pomme", the slug string I get is: "jai-mange-une-pomme" which, in french, is not correct. I would like "j-ai-mange-une-pomme".

It's not really an issue. I can do:

```
$slug = str_replace('\'','_',$input['name']);
$slug = str_slug($slug, '-');
```

It suits me well but I wonder how to use anytime I want to use it. I don't want to write it again and again and again.
In procedural, it's easy, I would write a function, such as `thePerfectSlug(){}` in a helpers.php file (still an example) and will use an include at the top of my index.php. That would do the job.

But in OOP and especially in Laravel (5.1), how can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Get your head out of the procedural model and put it into a class, make it a public static if you have to. Making it a global function pollutes the root namespace.  Every time you do that, god kills a kitten.

Answer (score 2):

You still can achieve it with normal function. Laravel uses his own function which are stored in helpers.php file. You can make your own helpers.php file and add it to your main composer.json file at autoload.files.

If you would like to do it in OOP way, create a trait like App\Traits\Sluggify with your method and use it in any class that needs it.

Comment: And yet another way is to create an facade that groups all the supporting functions. But in general, use create a helper lib and add to composer.json is the recommended way IMO

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I checked on the web how to do that and found some results. I'll try one of them but I wonder about the Laravel solution. I've seen that the real function is written in Str.php and is a `public static function` and a function that calls it, written in helpers.php. Should I do the same ? Why not using directly what's written in Str.php? Sorry if this question sounds really noob :).

Comment: I think it's done this way to make code developer write more clear and easier to write. It doesn't touch only Str things, but also Arr(ay) and probably much more. It's faster to write array_get then Arr::get and specify to use this class. That's why it's called helper :) However notice that env helper does not call any class, but has all logic inside a  function.

Comment: So I took a look at this, I created a folder in App I called Customs and a php file helpers.php. I cannot write it because of the inline mode of comments, but it seems to look right. I actually copied/pasted the Laravel function and added my str_replace. Sounds good but it does not load... The auload section of composer.json seems to say that it autoloads all the app folder so... Can you help me? Thanks for the explanation by the way :)