# Add your own helpers.php to composer.json

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

Following this topic [Use a custom function everywhere in the website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058779/use-a-custom-function-everywhere-in-the-website) I need a bit of help to finish what has been started.

So I created a folder in the app folder: Customs
Then I created a helpers.php file that has the following code:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

if (! function_exists('str_slug')) {
    /**
     * Generate a URL friendly "slug" from a given string.
     *
     * @param  string  $title
     * @param  string  $separator
     * @return string
     */
    function my_slug($title, $separator = '-')
    {
        $title = str_replace('\'','_',$title);
        return Str::slug($title, $separator);
    }
}
```

I read that I now have to update my composer.json, and especially the autoload section which is basically:

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
```

I don't understand what I should do now... psr-4 already says that the whole app folder is autoloaded, no?

I also tried to put the full path to the helpers.php but it did not work either.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Your autoload should have something like that:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/helpers.php"
    ]
},
```

where `files` are your custom files. Also as is mentioned in *Use a custom function everywhere in the website* question I advice you to use traits for e.g. `trait StringSluggify`. It keeps OOP way.

Comment: Thanks but I still have an issue : `Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\my_slug()`. I don't know what a trait is... I will take a look later.

Comment: @Ennicolem how do you use function `my_slug()`? Using pointer `$this->my_slug()` or not?

Comment: I am doing : `$input = Request::all();

     $publisher = new Publisher([
      'name' => $input['name'],
      'slug' => my_slug($input['name'],'-')
     ]);

     $publisher->save();`

Comment: This is unnecessary, `psr-4 already says that the whole app folder is autoloaded`

Comment: @manix No, that tells it to autoload classes only. If you want a function that's outside of any class to be available everywhere without manually including it, then you have to add it to the files array

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a folder inside of `app/` called `Helpers`.
2. Inside of `app/Helpers` create your custom class

   ```
   namespace App\Helpers;

   class FooHelper{

       public static function bar(){
           return 'bar';
       }
   }
   ```
3. Run `composer dump-autoload` to update autoload.

Here you are now able to use your helper functions like:

```
$bar = \App\Helper\FooHelper::bar();
```

If your plan is attach a **facade**, then edit facades array in `config/app.php` like so:

```
'Foo' => \App\Helpers\FooHelper::class
```

Now you can call your functions like:

```
public function controllerFunction(){
    $bar = \Foo::bar();
}
```

Comment: Hi, this is very helpful but not really in my case. Well I guess... There is already a class for the slug, what I would like is to improve it. Since Laravel is providing functions, why instead of creating a new class that will be 95% the same as the Laravel's one, I should not create a new function that use the class but add a new element ?

Answer (score 0):

use it in your view {{my_slug($collection->value)}} or in your controllers with the namespacing App\customs\my_slug($value) or by adding use \App\customs to the top of your controller and then my_slug($value)